# Flutter Bloc - is there a way to provide different instances of a bloc in a screen

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I have a cubit named FoodCubit which has two functions:

-getAllFoods()

-getFilteredFoods(category)

And I have a screen like below
[image: HomeScreen]

As you can see top part of the screen is a blocbuilder returning states emitted by my first function which is called in didChangeDependency()
And the bottom part is another blocbuilder of the same FoodCubit which I want to return states emitted by second function
But the results in top blocbuilder and bottom blocbuilder are the same. I used a blocprovider in parent of my material app providing FoodCubit. I was wandering if there is a way to provide two instances of same bloc and use it.
Some how like

```
MultiBlocProvider(
Providers:[
//first bloc provider
BlocProvider(), 
//second bloc provider
BlocProvider() 
)
```

But then how can I reach it in blocbuilder??

I think one work around is to use two blocproviders for top and bottom part of screen but wouldn't that just destroy purpose of using blocs.
Is there any way around it?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options you can try here:

1. Create a subclass of the bloc:

```dart
class FirstBloc extends FoodCubit {}
class SecondBloc extends FoodCubit {}
```

2. Create mixins of the bloc:

```dart
mixin FirstBloc on Bloc {}

mixin SecondBloc on Bloc {}

class FoodCubit extends Bloc with FirstBloc, SecondBloc {
  getAllFoods()

  getFilteredFoods(category)
}
// Then in your widget
... 
BlocProvider<FirstBloc>(
     create: (_) => FoodCubit(),
     child:
...
BlocProvider<SecondBloc>(
     create: (_) => FoodCubit(),
     child:
...
```

Comment: Thanks but in mixin approach how can I call functions provided in the original cubit. None of the functions exist :  context.read<SecondBloc>() has no function except Cubit's default functions

Comment: Double thx! I just started flutter and I was wondered, that I cann't create 2 instances of one bloc. You gave an explanation and some solution, if it needs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could just emit the same state for both events, that has a "all" list *and* a "filtered" list.

You would not need two BlocBuilders either, it could be just one.

Comment: I am emitting the same state thing is states data is different one of them is filtered. And it can't be one blocbuilder two different events are dispatched and their results are shown in two different places

Answer (score 0):

I would have emitted separate state from the different events of same bloc and in my blocBuilder i would define buildwhen property, so that my bloc builder would render the widget only when bloc emit the state for that particular widget.

```
abstract class FoodEvent extends Equatable {}
class GetFood extends FoodEvent{}
class FilterFood extends FoodEvent{}

abstract class FoodState extends Equatable {}
class AllFood extends FoodState{}
class FilteredFood extends FoodState{}

FoodBloc extends Bloc<FoodEvent, FoodState>{
FoodBloc():super(FoodState){
   on<GetFood>(_loadFood);
   on<FilterFood>(_filterFood);
 }

Future _loadFood(GetFood event, Emitter<FoodState> emit) async 
 {
  try {
    emit(AllFood());
   } catch (_) {}
 }

Future _filterFood(FilterFood event, Emitter<FoodState> emit) async 
 {
  try {
    emit(FilteredFood());
   } catch (_) {}
 }

}



BlocBuilder<BlocName>(
buildWhen:(current,previous) => current is FilterState;
builder: (context,state){
 if(state is FilterState)
   return FilterWidget();
  return const SizedBox.shrink();
 }
)
```

Hope it helps.